# Init FragmentActivity with a single fragment programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm tring to add a fragment to an activity in order to avoid declaring the layout xml. I'm doing

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, new mFragment()).commit();
}
```

But it crashes with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Is there a short form for avoiding this error or I must recover the content layout before and remove all their views? Thanks

Edit mFragment Code:

```
public class mFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: post code of your fragment class `mFragment`

Comment: See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973016/add-multiple-fragments-programmatically/11973156#11973156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
View result= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container);
```

To:

```
View result= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code while inflating.

```
View result= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
```

This will avoid adding the view to parent by default.
By using the other method, it will add a parent by default. So when you try to add it dynamically it will throw the above mentioned exception.